# How to install the jquery mobile(phonegap) in dreamweaver cs6

Tags: jquery, cordova, dreamweaver

I downloaded trial version of Dreamweaver CS6. I saw the tutorial on youtube and adobe and want to follow their step. But i have one problem i can not have the jquery mobile(phonegap) option under the mobile starter option of dreamweaver. What i should install for this to enable on my dw version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you found out how to do it. But in Dreamweaver CS6 you select JQuery Mobile(local) under mobile starter. I was a bit confused too about this but i tried that option and worked. Hope it helps..